# How to use concat with mongoose aggregate using $set

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

For example, I have a document as below.

```
{
   "test": "success"
}
```

And I want to add extra string value after "success".

```
{
   "test": "successfail"
}
```

Therefore I tried some aggregate using mongoose.

```
const Users = require("./userSchema")

Users.aggregate([
  {},
  [{ $set: { test: { $concat: [ "$test", "fail" ] } } }],
])
```

But this didn't work at all.
Could you recommend some solution for this? Thank you so much for reading this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To Concatenates string in the existing fields of a collection, you should use `$project` stage pipeline with `$concat` operator as below not the `$set` in the pipeline stage:

> Users.aggregate([
>     { $project: { test: { $concat: [ "$test", "", "fail" ] } } }
>   ])

For more details check the below queries with output also:

```
> db.st1.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5dffa38b4a36d14455f50158"), "test" : "success" }
> db.st1.aggregate([{$project: {test: {$concat: ["$test", "fail" ]  }  }  }])
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5dffa38b4a36d14455f50158"), "test" : "successfail" }
>
> db.st1.aggregate([{$project: {test: {$concat: ["$test", "-", "fail" ]  }  }  }])
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5dffa38b4a36d14455f50158"), "test" : "success-fail" }
> 
> db.st1.aggregate([{$project: {test: {$concat: ["$test", "", "fail" ]  }  }  }])
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5dffa38b4a36d14455f50158"), "test" : "successfail" }
```

For references visit the official documentation of MongoDB:

1. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concat/#concat-aggregation